# Bootstrap modal with paginated data from django view

Tags: jquery, django, twitter-bootstrap, pagination, modal-dialog

I am loading a bootstrap modal with the data coming from django view, and it is a paginated data i.e. 10 records per page.

It is showing the first page correctly but when I click on the next page link, it is being redirected to some other url, whereas I want to display the content of next page in the same modal appending to the previous data, like a loader on a click.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Can you provide your code?

Comment: If I got you.. You should define the pager with the url which you want to redirect. I would pass a parameter as well (by url, numberPage) which set the page where you are. The url recieve this param and call to controller for the respective 10 records setted by the page number. Then you only have to show de modal page with those data.

Comment: did you solve your problem?